# variable not defined vs variable set to null

Tags: terraform

I try to pass some parameters to the google pub sub terraform module where they use a code block like this

```
for_each = var.create_topic ? { for i in var.push_subscriptions : i.name => i if try(i.dead_letter_topic, "") != "" } : {}
```

When I pass variables for the push_subscription like:

```
  push_subscriptions = [
    {
      name                 = "push"
      push_endpoint        = "https://example.com/push"
      dead_letter_topic    = null
    },
  ]
```

I will get an error with:

```
 on .terraform/modules/pubsub/main.tf line 62, in resource "google_pubsub_topic_iam_member" "push_topic_binding":
│   62:   topic   = each.value.dead_letter_topic
│ 
│ The argument "topic" is required, but no definition was found.
```

When I completely remove the `dead_letter_topic` variable it works fine.

Im wondering why this is the case? I thought (and read) when something is null then terraform threads it like it does not exist? So in my opinion both options should result in the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to create a `google_pubsub_topic_iam_member` by passing the value of `dead_letter_topic` as the `topic` value for that resource. The `topic` value of that resource is a required value that you have to set. If `dead_letter_topic` is null, then you are trying to create a `google_pubsub_topic_iam_member` that has a null or empty string for a topic.

Terraform treats optional attributes as "unset" when you pass a null value. You can't do that at all for required attributes.

I believe the logic in your `for_each` is flawed. I think part of the problem may be that you are turning a list into a map, instead of a set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the for_each is from the google pub sub module ( https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-pubsub/blob/master/main.tf) and not my own code.

`dead_letter_topic` is optional for the module. That's why I wonder why null and not set makes a difference.

Comment: You should post this bug to that project's GitHub Issues then. You could also try setting empty string `""` instead of `null` as that appears to be what they are checking for.